# Link for download jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

Please Provide Exact Link for the  jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js

Answer (score 2):

According to http://jqueryui.com, the latest version of jQuery UI is 1.8.13.

You can build a custom download here: http://jqueryui.com/download

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is one for 1.8.14, as the lastest version is 1.8.14. But there is a Google CDN for 1.8.13:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js

It might be best to just download the whole thing again though.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no direct link, because (note the name) it's a custom created file. You populate it with the jQuery elements that you want to use. You can create your own here:

http://jqueryui.com/download